# Searching in mongodb using just few keywords

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using node js,mongoose,express and mongodb.

I have created simple form, in which you enter you full name and it searches in database and return your other details .

Is it possible to search using only few words out of the whole name? e.g. if the user wants to search for "abc xyz",can user do the same using only "abc" or "xyz"

this is my original route:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){

  var name = req.query.name;
  details.findOne({fullname:name},function(err,foundAsked){
      if(err){console.log("ERROR!!!");}
      else{res.render("Details.ejs",{foundAsked:foundAsked,name:name}); }
  });
 });
```

Is it possible to do that?if yes,then how can I implement that ?

Comment: As far as I know, in order to find an element you have to search for that exact element. However one thing you could do is create another element when adding to the db called "nickname" or something, set up your query to search on either name or nickname.

Comment: You can have a look at Mongo's text search capabilities [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex to partially match on certain fields like so

```
const query = {
    fullname: {
        $regex: req.query.name,
        $options: 'i'
    }
};

details.find(query, function(err, foundAsked){
  ...
})
```

Where the `i` in query is to make it case insensitive.

In the case of using partial search, I would recommend not using `findOne` as that might be misleading to the user to only return a single result if he/she types let's say `A`

Comment: it works fine.Just curious ,is it possible to resolve any clash ,if someone has same first name?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use regexes for that :

```
details.findOne({ fullname : /.*(?:abc|xyz).*/gi }, .....
```